# PHP - Error: No database selected - reading from a database issue

Tags: php, mysql, connection-string

I figured out hot to get contected to my database in line one I dont get a connection error anymore. But not Im getting an error that says no database selected. What could the issues be? Is my code correct?

First time reading from a mysql database in php. 
Thanks for the help.

```
<?php     

if (!($con = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pw'))) { 
   die('Connect failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con) or die('Error select: '.mysql_error()); 



$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM Gallerys') or die ('Error query: '.mysql_error ());

echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Thumb Url </th>
 <th>Gallery Url</th>
 </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['THUMBURL'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['GALLERYURL'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: remove your connection detail! You don't want to be hacked right?

Comment: mysql_connect, mysql **i** _connect_errno - ***I*** think that might be the cause of your problem ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to getting rid of `mysqli_...` function do the following:

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
```

That will tell you what happened when you were selecting database. I bet you don't have my_db or you don't have permission to open it.

---

Final resultion to anyone following this thread - the problem was with the name of the datbase. It was not my_db but something else.

Comment: I updated the code with your sugestions. I get the error (Error select: Access denied for user 'gallerys'@'%' to database 'my_db') Now.

Comment: I guess that would answer your question. You need to obtain permiission to the database.

Comment: Ah so my user id and password are wrong im using. thanks Ill check that.

Comment: What else could i be missing? I check my username and password and its correct for The database.

Comment: Its failing on this line (mysql_select_db("my_db", $con) or die('Error select: '.mysql_error()); ).... What is my_db?

Comment: Are username and password for the host and the database the same? Usually they are not. Anyway, just in case they are, you may have an sql server permission set that does not allow anyone to access from your IP address or from IP addresses from other than predefined range.

Comment: I am rewriting my post - mysql is a database system that contains many databases. To access database you use either `use db` query, which is the same as `mysql_select_db("db",$con);` or you specify the database in the query itself as for example `... from db.mytable ...`. Each database has privileges which can constrain access. For example only for the local users (127.0.0.1) If this is the case then you cannot access it. You can ask the database admin t check privileges for you.

Comment: Hmm I just set up a new db and I entered a user name and Password for the db. Im copying and pasting that exactly as is. what do you mean the password for the Host? I had to set up a read only user name and password do i need to use that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15995/discussion-between-grzegorz-and-csharpbeginner)

Comment: Im using godaddys online database mysql manager nothing on my local machine. Im creating my page on dreamweaver and then FTping it up to the server and accessing it via the web. Would that process cause the problems?

Answer (score 2):

Your connect-code is using `mysql_connect`, but your error-checking is using `mysqli`:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Try updating to:

```
if (!($con = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass'))) {
    die('Connect failed: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Alternatively, you could update all of the references to `mysql_*` functions to actually use the `mysqli_*` functions - as this is recommended. This is a long-way-around to solve the problem at hand though, but it should also solve the problem.

Sample with mysqli:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name');
if (!$con) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Just as a small side note: `!$con = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass')` -- this would work as expected as well.

Comment: @zerkms I know, however, I use Netbeans as my regular IDE; it gives a "suggestion"-highlight when attempting to assign something in a conditional-check to wrap the assignment in an additional set of parentheses so that you, and whoever-else reads your code **knows** you mean to do the assignment inside the conditional check

Comment: I updated the code with your sugestions now i get the error code (Error select: Access denied for user 'gallerys'@'%' to database 'my_db')